# how to configure SBT to pick the desired scala version (2.9)

Tags: scala, sbt

While creating a project with sbt command it always prompts for the 2.7.X version of scala however I have 2.9.0 and sbt 0.7.7 installed is there a way to configure sbt to pick 2.9 by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use [sbt version 0.10](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) instead it has changed a bit, in the `build.sbt` file you specify `scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"` (default seem to be 2.8.1)

See [Migrating from SBT 0.7.x to 0.10.x](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Migrating-from-SBT-0.7.x-to-0.10.x) or [Quick Configuration Examples](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Quick-Configuration-Examples). [The Full configuration example](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration-Example) shows Scala style configuration.

Threre is a  `~/.sbt/plugins/` library where you store global plugins. But I do not yet know if you can define a global build properties.

Comment: I tried with sbt version 0.10, when issued sbt I get and 
`[INFO] set current project as default (path of the project)`
and no src folders are created ... any help on this ..

Comment: I dont think it creates folders anymore, it Sbt uses the same directory structure as Maven for source files by default, see https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup for more information

Comment: so is that we have to create them manually following maven's conventions

Comment: or create a template project that you copy when you create a new project that contains all you need. That is what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory there should be a file called build.properties. There you can configure SBT to use whatever version you want. When you change the file either exit SBT or use the command reload.

Comment: That's not what he meant. He means when creating a NEW project.