# SBT - Scala version mismatch

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

I have the latest Scala IDE 3.0 installed on Eclipse 4.2.2

I installed the latest SBT using `brew install sbt`

When I run SBT and type the command `console` this is what I get

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_43).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Where did the Scala REPL 2.9.2 come from?

Comment: have you checked your sbt config files?

Comment: take a look at your project directory: there might be `./build.sbt` and/or `./project/Build.scala` (or SomeOtherName.scala) files. Most likely you'll see `scalaVersion := "2.9.2"` line inside of them.

Comment: There is a "target/scala-2.9.2" subdirectory. The weird thing is the project was created in Eclipse which is using scala 2.10.1

Comment: `/target` directories **doesn't matter at all** (it just a place  for temporary build files), please, look for a files I've mentioned above. If there is no such files [create one with desired scala version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247075/how-to-configure-sbt-to-pick-the-desired-scala-version-2-9).