# Where is the default scalaVersion sbt uses?

Tags: scala, sbt

Just out of curiosity, I would like to know whether the default `scalaVersion` that sbt uses is somehow hard-coded in the source? I mean the version for all projects that don't specify a scala version explicitly (via the `scalaVersion` setting key)

I ask this because, on my machine, I'm using sbt 0.12.4 and no `build.sbt` files anywhere (neither project root, nor in `project` or `~/.sbt/plugins`), and when I type `sbt about` I get this:

```
...
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2
```

I'm already using scala 2.10.2 (in my `PATH`) but I reckon this install has nothing to do with sbt, as it downloads scala from the official repos.

There are many similar questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247075/how-to-configure-sbt-to-pick-the-desired-scala-version-2-9) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768730/how-to-inform-sbt-to-consume-specific-scala-version-for-plugins), but they only refer to a specific project.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, sbt will build projects with the same version of Scala used to run sbt itself.  But the ~/.sbt/boot directory downloads scala jars from the repository, similarly to plugin jars - so the default scala version is a dependency of sbt configured in the repository.  Means that as sbt versions march forward, so the default scala version will march forward, as configured by sbt devs.

This can be confirmed by viewing plugins/target/resolution-cache/reports/default-global-plugins-scala-tool.xml (and also same content in runtime-resolved.xml):

```
<module organisation="org.scala-lang" name="scala-compiler">
<revision name="2.10.2" status="release" pubdate="20130607040625" resolver="sbt-chain" artresolver="sbt-chain" homepage="http://www.scala-lang.org/" downloaded="false" searched="false" default="false" conf="default, optional, compile, runtime, optional(default), master" position="0">
    <license name="BSD-like" url="http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/license.html    "/>
    <metadata-artifact status="no" details="" size="2843" time="0" location="C:\Users\Bestos\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\ivy-2.10.2.xml" searched="false" origin-is-local="false" origin-location="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.pom"/>
    <caller organisation="default" name="global-plugins" conf="scala-tool" rev="2.10.2" rev-constraint-default="2.10.2" rev-constraint-dynamic="2.10.2" callerrev="0.0"/>
    <artifacts>
        <artifact name="scala-compiler" type="jar" ext="jar" status="no" details="" size="14411577" time="0" location="C:\Users\Bestos\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\jars\scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar">
            <origin-location is-local="false" location="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar"/>
        </artifact>
    </artifacts>
</revision>
</module>
```

Of course, the scala version used for individual projects can be configured differently to the "bootstrap scala version" via the setting `scalaVersion`.  Within build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I think I actually found out the line where the default version is hard coded by sbt devs: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.12.4/project/Sbt.scala#L19 - But if the bootstrap scalaVersion were the same as I ran sbt with, as you said, it should be 2.10.2 (scala install on my `PATH`), when it's actually still 2.9.2..would you agree? (I'm using sbt 0.12.4)

Comment: For the bootstrap scala version, I believe it ignores the SCALA_HOME, PATH and scala installation and hard-wires it's own dependencies on the jars - which are downloaded to ~/.sbt/boot.  Thanks for pointing out the line of code - the dependendency is declared in the code (I thought it was implicitly determined within the repository).  Sbt 0.12.x bootstraps with scala 2.9.2, sbt 0.13.x bootstraps with scala 2.10.2 (here's the updated line of code https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.0/project/Sbt.scala) :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was wondering. Of course, we should all define our plugin versions and let sbt do the scalaVersion dependency work. Thanks!